# Modal ViewController Appearing Black in Xcode 9 Beta 4 on Multiple iOS Versions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing my app using Xcode 9 beta 4 and I'm randomly getting a black screen whenever my modal pops up. I've tried various ways to fix it and I was wondering if any of you have suggestions. Right now I just use the basic '[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toVC" sender:nil];' and I've got the segue and such setup properly. The biggest issue is that it's seemingly random! As in sometimes the view loads perfectly fine and sometimes it just loads black.

[The black image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sekIq.png)

I have absolutely zero idea why this is happening. I've tested on the iOS 10.0 simulator and the iOS 11.0 beta 4 simulator and it happens in both places. If any of you have any insight as to why this is happening then please let me know.

Comment: Can you post more details for the view controller you are presenting? Do you have a custom subclass for it? Does the same problem happen for any view controller you try to present, or just this one?

Answer (score 0):

Release notes:

Simulator devices will show as all black on some hardware. (32436030)
Workaround:

`defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 1`

to force use of Metal. If that doesn't work, try 2 (force use of OpenCL).

- from Apple Dev Forums